# Generating bounding box to predictions from keras image segmentation

Tags: tensorflow, keras, mask, image-segmentation, bounding-box

I have implemented one of the [keras examples](https://keras.io/examples/vision/oxford_pets_image_segmentation/) to detect certain objects in an image. The code can already satisfatorily detect some of the objects - please check the next image: [Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iK1th.jpg)

I would like to generate a bounding box to each of the objects with label, such as: [Image1-boundingbox example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oKMw.jpg)

Could you please provide suggestions on the most efficient way to produce these boxes?

Furthermore, I would like to create a unidimensional color mask with the area of the objects. I have checked on contours from `cv2`, but would like to also ask you if there is a better way to implement it.